# Why Doesn't nexus index list snaphot jars?

Tags: maven, nexus, maven-indexer

Nexus index lists pom, zip, test.jar, sources.jar and docs.zip for my snapshot but doesn't list the jar artifact.

- Nexus view of storage shows the jar
- Maven users pulling deps from this instance regularly down the jar

Is there a way to get it to show in the search and index with a download link or is the default artifact unlisted on purpose (I guess because I should always access it via pom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samuel and I discussed the issue in the other answer.   It seems this is working as designed probably due to the transient nature of snapshots.

You can find the snapshot jars (or default artifacts) via the full url and by browsing the storage but they do not show up in the index or the web UI search.

Answer (score 1):

You can, it works for me :

I don't see the snapshot jars in the browse index tab, but I see them in browse storage tab, and I can also see them in my web browser, seeing something like this :

https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.8.4-SNAPSHOT/

I use : 
Sonatype Nexus™ Open Source Edition, Version: 1.9.2

Comment: Hi Samuel,  the index tab and the search is where I fail to see them as well.  So, we match in where we can and can't see them.  I think this isn't a bug and is part of an intentional design.

Comment: Probably, it makes sense to see only the availability of a snapshot, and not every details, presence of timestamped jars... especially on public repo, where people could be tempted to harcode a specific jar. This could lead to troubles, as there is no guarantee that a SNAPSHOT jar should remain available "forever"